# Signoff previous in between commits in git

Tags: git, git-commit

I have a branch where there are multiple commits as below

```
Commit 1 - Not signed
Commit 2 - Signed off X
Commit 3 - Not signed
Commit 4 - Not signed
Commit 5 - Signed off by Y
```

i would like to signoff the commits 1, 3, 4 . Those are the ones i created and missed to sign off

When i try to do using

```
git rebase HEAD~3 --signoff
```

Its signing the commit number 2 which was already signed off by X.

Is there any way we can specifically sign off specific commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a few commits, use an [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History), set those commits to edit, and `git commit --amend --signoff` on each of them.

Comment: [`git rebase -i -x "git commit --amend --signoff" HEAD~3`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--xltcmdgt)

Comment: @phd Does that execute for all `pick`ed commits?

Comment: Yes, non-interactive (automatic) interactive rebase. :-)

Comment: @phd I think that's what the OP is trying to avoid, overwriting existing signatures.

Comment: The resulting rebase todo file can be edited to remove `exec` line(s).

Comment: @phd Interesting. I've never played with `-x`. Could you write up an answer?

Answer (score 4):

Use interactive rebase + [`--exec`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--xltcmdgt):

```
git rebase -i -x "git commit --amend --no-edit --signoff" HEAD~3
```

When `git rebase -i` presents you with its todo file remove `exec` line from under commit 2. Left all other commands (`pick` and `exec`) intact. Save and `git rebase -i` will run the commands for you completely automatically.

PS. Backup the repo.